# How to 'flatten' a C++ COM DLL to standard exported methods? (Consumed by c#)

Tags: c#, c++, dll, com

We have an in-house code C++ COM library. We are currently consuming the library from a C# application. Works fine.

However, the registration and unregistration of COM objects is tedious and is starting to be a problem for users upgrading to win7 due to the need for running the registration with admin priviledges (not possible directly from our Click-once application).

So... Since we really have no reason for using the library through COM (it's coded as COM for historic reasons), we'd like to switch to just exposing methods as 'plain exports'.

First attempt was just exposing the methods next to the COM Classes. Looks fine through appropriate tools for inspecting dlls.

Now, when I remove the COM reference in VS and include the dll by just 'browsing' in the add-reference dialog, it is still treated as a COM object and the dll is not included in output as I would expect.

Is it 'illegal' to use a COM library as simple dll? What is the best way through this problem?

Thanks for any input!

Anders, Denmark

Comment: So you want to stop using COM and start using P/Invoke?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use the add references dialogs to add a DLL, even if it wasn't a COM one. Now as it is COM it recognizes it and loads it at a COM object.

The simplest solution is probably to use registration free COM, which means you can deploy the DLL with your application rather than actually having to register it, but you still talk to it as a COM object. It is just a case of manipulating your manifest file.

Try the tool at [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28682/regsvr42-Generate-SxS-Manifest-Files-from-Native-D) to help you generate the manifest, or a search on here for registration free COM.

Comment: Yep, I recommend registration-free COM as well. Using the raw functions is possible, but you'd have to manually translate their signatures into PInvoke signatures in C#, you can't use "add reference" for that. The reason is that regular DLLs have no metadata (other than the names of the exported functions). In C/C++ you have the header to help you use the DLL, but C# can't use those, so it needs you to tell it what the function signatures are. There is no type library to import (which is what add reference uses for a COM DLL).

Answer (score 1):

To have the DLL in the output you should have the Embed Interop types set to true

[more on this from MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997297.aspx)

Comment: That sounds like it would still be using COM...?

Comment: @crashmstr well, yes. I guess, I didn't understand the question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what, specifically, causes you to need admin privileges?  If it's the COM registration, you could try registering the DLLs in HKCU\Software\Classes instead of HKCR.